# How to find all files which paths contains a specific directories

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find all files which have the following path:

```
/usr/local/.../site-admin/data.sh
```

I mean I wanta find all such `data.sh` which are located in `site-admin`. Note, that `/usr/local` may contain multiple `site-admin` directoires. How can I do that?

Comment: In `zsh` you could write directly: `/usr/local/**/site-admin/data.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find /usr/local -name 'data.sh'
```

If you want `data.sh` to be in `/site-admin/` only

```
find /usr/local -path '*/site-admin/data.sh'
```

Comment: How do you match the `site-admin` subdirectory?

Comment: I think he's looking for files called `data.sh` which lie in directories called `site-admin`

Comment: Is it possible to modify that command to perform lookup by the regex of a file name?

Comment: Have updated another example for `site-admin/data.sh`

Comment: @St.Antario: Instead of regex it uses glob pattern. Using regex it will be: **`find /usr/local -regex '.*/site-admin/data.sh'`**

Comment: I think the OP wants to find all data.sh files within site-admin. Your answer will return data.sh even if it is inside /usr/local.

Comment: @bot: Starting path can be even root also so OP can use: **`find / -path '*/site-admin/data.sh'`**

Answer (score 1):

You will also want to grep so you are sure the file is in a directory site-admin:

```
find /usr/local -name data.sh | grep site-admin/data.sh$
```